# need for sending data in URLencoded format

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, npm, mongoose

I am new to node.js and API development.And during presentation I was given a question which I was not sure was.
I had made a REST API(contact catalog kind of )and data was send through postman (url encoded-POST request) and saved after some manipulation in mongoDB .
So the question was that what is the reason to url-encode the data when intially it is in JSON format and again saved back in JSON format in DB only.
Any particular reason except for encryption purpose?
FYI-backend was in node.js

Comment: Please include more details.

Comment: You should be sending a `JSON string` in the request body in the POST request and add a header `application/json` as I understand about your question. No need to url encode the JSON. Url encoding is done while passing the data in the query string to make it url safe.

Comment: @Abhishek Soni Please have a look at below description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to have your REST concepts clear while you write APIs.

I will list down methods to use and when to use and from where you can send the data.

**METHOD => USE => SEND DATA IN**

- GET => Fetch data => Request (Query, params, headers)
- POST => Create new => Request (Query, params, headers, **body**)
- PUT => Update data => Request (Query, params, headers, **body**)
- DELETE => Remove data => Request (Query, params, headers, **body**)

So in your case, you are trying to create the data and using REQUEST QUERY (URL Encoded), you don't need this.

You need to change the method to POST and send data in the request body as JSON.

Hope this clears your thoughts. :)